# how to kill Async task after a specific time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

how to kill Async task after a specific time.

Here is My code

```
public class EnterTextAsyc extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    /* displays the progress dialog untill background task is completed */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog(context, "Please Wait !!!!!...");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    /* Task of EnterTextAsyc performing in the background */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVERPORT);
            out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));
            out.write(("BE").getBytes());
            ServerData = in.readLine();
            if (ServerData == null || ServerData.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                ServerData = "IsNull";
            }

        } catch (NetworkOnMainThreadException e) {
            ServerData = "IsNull";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ServerData = "IsNull";
        }

        return null;
    }
```

How to set a timeout message if there is no response from Server(ServerData = in.readLine();).

Comment: You can use a timer or a thread,runnable to count down your desired time, and after x ms you can kill the async task

Comment: the handling of the timeout here should be set in the socket directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Handler h;
private static final int DELAY=3000; //milis

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            if(h!=null)
                h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            cancelAfterTimeout(true);
        }
    }, DELAY);
    progressDialog(context, "Please Wait !!!!!...");
    super.onPreExecute();
}

private void cancelAfterTimeout(boolean interrupt){
    //cancel/force interrupt/dissable/remove connection here
    //which you are initializing in doInBackground
    cancel(interrupt);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    if(h!=null)
        h.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

even if you pass mayInterrupt as true the connection is still executing, you might create new method for cancelling online connections and then `super.cancel(true);`. more info and some methods for override [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165860/asynctask-oncancelled-not-being-called-after-canceltrue) - `onCanceled()` and `onCanceled(Boolean result)` for you

PS canceling `Socket` connection while executing might be difficult, thread about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701073/how-can-a-socket-be-both-connected-and-closed/3701249) . maybe try `HttpClient` or `HTTPConnection`?

Comment: this solution sol my problem but i am not able to cancel Socket connection, its run background. please help me?

Comment: like I suggested you in last paragraph: use HttpClient or HttpConnecion or other "cancelable" method. example for simple httpClient and GET method here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400258/cancel-an-httpclient-request

Comment: i does not  want use another connection, there is no way to cancel socket connection??. i am use socket.close(); but this code not working for mi.

Comment: `Socket` connection may be cancelled only by server-side as I know... there is `Socket.close();` method, but is only flagging connection for `isClosed()`. check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891044/in-android-how-to-stop-a-thread-that-is-wating-for-a-new-socket) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701073/how-can-a-socket-be-both-connected-and-closed/3701249) thread, maybe it helps you